# term for concrete category with initial morphism for each element

Tags: category-theory

I need a term for a concrete category over Set with a distinguished object $i,$ such that the morphisms from $i$ correspond to elements of the other objects. More formally, for every object $o$ and every element $x \in o,$ there is exactly one morphism $m_{o,x}: i \to O.$ Is this an established concept, and, if so, what is the nomenclature.

Note that the terms initial and pointed already have other meanings in category theory.

The question arose while revising https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.05775

Comment: Hi, did you write that paper?

Comment: Do you mean something like the one-point set in category **Set** ?

Comment: @magma Yes, I wrote the paper, but I am working on a revision. Something like the one-point set in category **Set**, but for concrete categories over **Top**.

Comment: I was interested in a similar concept: a concrete category with an object i and a distinguished element e of i, such that for any o and any x in o there is a unique morphism : i→o  sending e to x. I called it an "egg" (settheory.net/algebra/basis)
because not only it is made of 2 things (an object and an element), but we have a concept of "clone", that is a sequence of things, the 1st entry of which happens to be the egg, and the n-th entry is the n-th coproduct of the egg with itself. If anyone knows a more accepted name for this, please tell.

Answer (score 6):

If what you're after is a concrete category where $U$ is representable, then such categories are called representably concrete.

Comment: What I was looking for is probably the term **generator** (or **separator**.), but the definitions in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/separator and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(category_theory) don't match. I need the term as defined in Wiki. Also, is there a term for a category with a generator?

Comment: @shmuel - Isn't the definition in one of those just the contrapositive of the other?

Comment: No; the nlab definition doesn't require that there be arrows from the generator to every other object.